# Authenticating to Calendar with Python gdata and oAuth 2

Tags: python, gdata, oauth-2.0

I'm migrating a Python application from oAuth 1 to oAuth 2 that reads a user's Google
calendar feed.

- With oAuth 1:
  My app would open a browser were user can authenticate with his GMail
  account and authorize access, and my app would obtain a user_token,
  user_secret for that user, then authenticate to the calendar feed:

  ```
  client = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient(source='test')
  client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken(app_key,
           app_secret,user_token,user_secret,gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
  ```

This token, secret pair would be long lived.

- With oAuth 2:
  I registered my app in the Google API console and obtained the oAuth 2
  client_id and client_secret, and modified the app to request the
  user's access_token, refresh_token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  For the GData lib, I applied the gauth.py patch specified here:
  http://codereview.appspot.com/4440067/

This access_token is short lived.

I played a little bit with the code posted here http://codereview.appspot.com/4440067/
and works ok.

My questions:

-I am obtaining access_token, refresh_token via a curl call from my
app, and I can successfully retrieve both. However, when I apply it to
this code:

```
    token =
    gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret',
                           scope='https://www.google.com/calendar/
    feeds',user_agent='calendar-cmdline-sample/1.0')
    uri = token.generate_authorize_url()
    token.get_access_token(access_token)
```

It gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/gdata/gauth.py", line 1267,
in get_access_token
   raise OAuth2AccessTokenError(error_msg)
gdata.gauth.OAuth2AccessTokenError
```

-Assuming I can successfully do the above, I can save the access/refresh tokens in a DB. Using python gdata lib, how can I use refresh_token to request another access_token (hence not having to ask the user every time they use the app to authorize access to it)

Thanks much in advance!

M

Answer (score 1):

Marchie,

I don't see the rest of your stack trace, but can give three particular issues with corresponding solutions that will solve your overall problem.

**Problem I**: The value `redirect_uri` is not set on the object.

Note how the body of the request is specified in `get_access_token`:

```
body = urllib.urlencode({
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'client_id': self.client_id,
  'client_secret': self.client_secret,
  'code': code,
  'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri,
  'scope': self.scope
  })
```

This depends on the `redirect_uri` property being set on the object to the value that was originally set in `generate_authorize_url`. So, after reconstructing the token by calling

```
token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(...)
```

you will simply need to set the redirect URI:

```
token.redirect_uri = 'http://path/that/you/set'
```

**Problem II**: The default value of `redirect_uri` is incorrect (more specifically, deprecated).

Since you called `generate_authorize_url` with no arguments, the default value for `redirect_uri` was used, which is currently `oob`. As the [OAuth 2.0 docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi) state, the `oob` is not among the supported values (it has been deprecated).

If you are indeed using an Installed Application, you will need to instead set it to

```
token.redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
```

In addition, when you call `generate_authorize_url` to get the initial token, you will need to use this as a keyword parameter

```
url = token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
```

**Problem III**: You are calling `get_access_token` with the incorrect value (also one that hasn't been instantiated in your code snippet).

You should either call this with a string value of the code you receive after authorizing or with a dictionary that has `'code'` as a key.

This can be done via the following:

```
import atom.http_core

# Page the user is redirected to after authorizing
redirected_page = 'http://path/that/you/set?code=RANDOM-CODE'
uri = atom.http_core.ParseUri(redirected_page)

# uri.query is a dictionary with the query string as key, value pairs
token.get_access_token(uri.query)
```

**Post Script**: The author of the [patch](http://codereview.appspot.com/4440067/) also published a [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/python-oauth-20-google-data-apis.html) on using the patch. (Note there is a typo in the post when the keyword `redirect_url` is used instead of `redirect_uri` in the `generate_authorize_url` function.)